# How to pass varargs in Spring shell with kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-shell

I am trying to write a spring shell app and pass some var args. Basicaly I want to pass

`fetch FA-207542 FA-207984 FA-211258  FA-202298`
Documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_infinite_arity) is still TBD

```kotlin
    @ShellMethod(value = "fetches all pic related data for processing")
    fun fetch(vararg tickets: String) {
        println("number of tickets is ${tickets.size}")
    }
```

results

```
shell:>fetch FA-207542 FA-207984 FA-211258  FA-202298
number of tickets is 1
```

I've tried using a `StringArray` and I get an error:

```kotlin
    fun fetch(tickets: StringArray) {
        println("number of tickets is ${tickets.size()}")
    }
```

error:

```
shell:>fetch FA-207542 FA-207984 FA-211258 FA-202298
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method FetchCommand.fetch, parameter tickets
Details of the error have been omitted. You can use the stacktrace command to print the full stacktrace.
```

Comment: it seems to work also super without any `arity` option, one thing you are missing is: `--tickets` (parameter name...which matches the exception message) ..of course things get also more complicated with "positional parameter" or when varargs is not "last parameter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [java](/questions/tagged/java) (sry), I got this working:

```java
@ShellComponent
public class MyCommands {

  @ShellMethod
  public String fetch(String... tickets) {
    return String.format("Number of tickets is %d.", tickets.length);
  }
}
```

then:

```bash
shell:>fetch --tickets FA-207542 FA-207984 FA-211258 FA-202298
Number of tickets is 4.
shell:>
```

---

Same results achieved with: `@ShellCommand(arity = -1)` resp. `arity = Integer.MAX_VALUE`.#

Comment: Ok, so usage of `--tickets` is what I need. I was hoping to not use such syntax. But, maybe it's necessary